# How can i subscribe the important release of Gnosis safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

We Deployed a fork of Gnosis for our own chain, and we have run several services for the gnosis safe web.

- safe-contracts
- safe-config-service
- safe-transaction-service
- safe-client-gateway
- safe-react

Is there any official channel where we can subscribe to the important change or upgrade of those services to avoid security risks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can subscribe on GitHub to the releases as all of these repositories create a new release for a new version.

We do have a discord for the Safe project (https://chat.gnosis-safe.io) where we do general announcements. There is also a `releases` announcement channel where you will got notified about new releases.